# Problem with wifi : Connection lost on closing laptop's lid

Tags: wireless, networking

I am having a weird problem with my laptop wifi, it does not have any problems when I'm working on it also if I leave the laptop lid open it does not have any problems or when the screen turns off

But if I closed the laptop lid the connection to the wifi network is lost within 10 minutes

```
alexander@Alexander-PC:~$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:f3:95:e8:36:35  
          inet addr:192.168.2.4  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::72f3:95ff:fee8:3635/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:54751 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:38151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:64134836 (64.1 MB)  TX bytes:4594568 (4.5 MB)
```

I have Ubuntu 14.04 x64
I used to have the same problem even on previous Ubuntu version but not on windows
.
My wifi encryption is

[image]

[image]
any ideas ?

Comment: The links to images you provided do not work.